# Free memory by external function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Inside `main()` I made pointer *p* and allocated it by `malloc()`; then I set its internal value (*data*) to *222*. For some reason I need a function which:
**First:** frees the memory of the pointer.
**Second:** makes the pointer point to new structure. I did it by *bar* function. (It works properly and the output is correct.)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct foo_s
    {
        int data;
    } foo;
    
    void bar(foo *f)
    {
        free(f);
    
        foo *g = malloc(sizeof(foo));
        g->data = 333;
    
        f = g;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
       foo *p = malloc(sizeof(foo));
       p->data = 222;
    
       bar(p);
       printf("%d", p->data);
    }
    // output is 333
```

but when I move `free` to several few lines below (somewhere that shouldn't change the result), the output shows something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct foo_s
{
    int data;
} foo;

void bar(foo *f)
{
    foo *g = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    g->data = 333;

    free(f); // moved here

    f = g;
}

int main()
{
   foo *p = malloc(sizeof(foo));
   p->data = 222;

   bar(p);
   printf("%d", p->data);
}
// output is 7149104
```

Where is the problem? Why aren't the results the same?

Comment: `bar()` needs a pointer to a pointer if you want to change what the pointer points to in a way visible to the caller.

Comment: If the first worked, it was a complete fluke. You would need to return the new pointer value and call as `p = bar(p);`

Comment: As it is, `p` in `main()` still points to the old now-freed address and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: The first code snippet has undefined behavior: `main` uses a pointer after it has been freed. The code appears to work, but that's just by chance, not by design. And that's one of the problems with undefined behavior. Sometimes you can't detect the problem with testing, because the code appears to work, but works for the wrong reasons.

Comment: The second example can't possibly "work" because you allocated more memory *before* `free`ing the previous. So the two pointers cannot possibly have the same value, which they must have done in the first example. It exposes the error in your concept.

Comment: There is a very simple way to eliminate 90% of the questions like this, or at least turn them into real useful questions. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/r9b4nGfe6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `bar()` function frees the address passed to it, but in `main()`, after calling `bar(p)`, `p` still points to the old, now-freed memory address. Dereferencing that is undefined behavior; all sorts of things might happen from seeing the old number, the new number, some random value, your program might crash or summon nasal demons... basically, you can't do that. `bar()` needs to take a pointer to a pointer so it can modify a variable in the caller's scope:

```c
void bar(foo **f)
{
    foo *g = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    g->data = 333;

    free(*f);

    *f = g;
}
```

and then be called as `bar(&p)`. Alternatively, `bar()` can return the new address, and be used as `p = bar(p);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void bar(foo *f)
{
    foo *g = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    g->data = 333;

    free(f); // moved here

    f = g;
}
```

All the `free` & `malloc` magic is not needed. Why to alloc new memory if you already have it for this type? Makes no sense at all.

```
void bar(foo *f)
{
    f->data = 333;
}
```